# Nvidia GT750M driver Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

I configured my graphic card with the nvidia driver-331 by terminal with the command explained in this guide.

http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/06/13/howto-install-nvidia-331-bumblebee-optimus-cards-ubuntu/

However my graphic card not works, and it is not visible from Ubuntu.

After typing:

```
    lspci -v | less
```

it answer:

```
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!!Unknown header type 7f
```

Can anyone help me?!?! 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To install Nvidia Drivers, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If that doesn't work, you can download the 32bit or 64bit drivers from Nvidia.

Comment: Thanks. Firstly, I have to purge nvidia-331, is it right? or not?

Comment: Probably best .

Comment: So before I type 'sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-331*' is it right?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331

Comment: Ok. I have worked with ubuntu for 6 mouth and I've got the nvidia driver until yesterday. Yesterday ubuntu did not start until I purge nvidia driver with the emergency terminal. I have a dual boot with windows and it works well, I'm doing a stress test of the GPU too. What's happen on my notebook?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what:
What's happen on my notebook? 
means.

Comment: yesterday it had worked perfectly but this morning it did not start until I have purged the nvidia driver. I think that the GPU might be broken. Is it possible? Have you an another idea of the causes of this stop?

Comment: Im sorry did the above not work?

Comment: It did not work. When I type in the terminal _nvidia-settings_ I obtain this message: 'ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.'

Answer (score -2):

DO NOT. I REPEAT DO NOT INSTALL THE DRIVERS FROM NVIDIA!!!

I did that and i just had to reinstall my whole system. spend two days trying to fix my Xserver and gave up. they do something to prevent xserver from starting. in my case they changed a bunch of permissions and ownership of xserver files, as well as prevented X from finding a screen.